# Thoughts on how to refer to web.config key names in code

Tags: asp.net, web-config

When your web.config or app.config file has an appsettings entry, what is the best way to refer to its key in your code file?

Developers I have worked with have differing opinions on this.  Some say to hard code the string and others suggest that there should be a file containing string constants and in your code, you use the constant as the appsettings key.

I would be interested in hearing other opinions on this.  What do you do?  Why is it the best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip the string constants, and create a configuration wrapper class instead.

```
class MyConfiguration
{
    public static string SomeConfigValue
    {
        get
        {
            return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeConfigValue"];
        }
    }

    public static int SomeOtherConfigValue
    {
        get
        {
            return int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeOtherConfigValue"];
        }
    }

    //..and so on
}
```

Then you could get it like this:

```
string s = MyConfiguration.SomeConfigValue;
int i = MyConfiguration.SomeOtherConfigValue;
```

(You might consider not going the static route if you want to remove dependencies on the configuration system while unittesting)

Comment: I've gone this route many times but can quickly become unwieldy. I think the custom configuration section is the way to go.

Comment: I like this method.  Its type safe (assuming the correct data is in the config file) and it makes refactoring easy.

Comment: One big downside to this method--mainly due to static nature--you can't test it, at least not without having multiple configuration files.

Answer (score 5):

String constants are better than nothing, but I'd initially vote for using a configuration class to provide strongly typed, intellisense friendly access to the config values. If I were stuck with using AppSettings for some reason.

In a more perfect world, I would vote for avoiding appSettings altogether and using custom configuration classes as they are much, much cleaner in the long run.

Comment: It's certainly nice to be able to strongly-type the settings properties using a built-in or custom type converter, organize the structure intuitively, etc.

Answer (score 2):

String Constants for the win.

Keeping common strings in string constants makes things easier to maintain. If a key in your config file changes names, you only have to change it in one spot rather than worrying about finding every instance of the hard-coded string throughout your application.

Comment: yep, there is no good answer when dealing with magic strings, but constants are usually the best.  Internal, unless they are never to change.  And a clear error should be thrown if the keys are not found.

Answer (score 1):

[I've always been a fan of Rick Strahl's method.](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/configurationclass/configurationclass.asp)

As for static strings being unwieldy, break your class down into subclasses and properties if you need to. For example in an application I'm currently working on, I have App.Settings for general settings, App.EmailSettings for email settings, and App.EventSettings for event logging settings.